# Uploading HTML files containing special characters on server destroys them

Tags: html

The title is pretty self explanatory.

I've never encountered this problem before. Only when I've tried to upload text with special characters on a database, but this is not the case.

I have HTML files that contain special characters like - āšķī etc. All of them are changed to some ?arab? letters after I upload the files on server.

What could be the solution?

Comment: What upload method are you using? What encoding type have you defined?

Comment: Disclosure: I'm new. I'm just straight up dropping trough Filezilla and I'm not sure about encoding type.

Answer (score -2):

Unicode

Unicode text files can store text in any language known to humanity. Modern globalized applications often use UTF-8 or UTF-16 to save text files.

UTF-8
UTF-16 little endian
UTF-16 big endian
UTF-32 little endian
UTF-32 big endian

Comment: And how is this helpful?

Comment: I meant first you have to save the files as a Unicode file.